# Flutter can't compile for iOS Error with pods

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies

Compiling for iOS was working for a awhile, I added some dependencies and switched to my android emu for a bit, now it won't compile for iOS.

I've tried making a fresh project and running that on iOS but I keep getting the same error.

PubSpec:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.11
  flutter_map: any # or the latest version on Pub
  location: ^4.3.0
```

Error:

```
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c (LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:393:in `source_with_url'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `block in sources'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `map'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:177:in `sources'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1077:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
Exception: Error running pod install
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to uninstall then install cocoapods?

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
brew install cocoapods
```